# High Charts Dynamically Expanding Graph

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have a stacked graph that could potentially have a very large number of columns and categories.

Is there a way to get a stacked graph to expand vertically when too many rows are specified.

For example, in

https://jsfiddle.net/vnx2ghgv/

You can see that some of the bars don't have labels on the y axis as they are too scrunched together, and it becomes harder to read the narrow bars.

The numbers in the graph `1` ... `24` are obfuscated but generally they would be usernames which can't be inferred.

Comment: have you seen drilldown bars of highcharts? or you want something like scrollable?

Comment: Check [this request](https://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-highcharts-javascript-api/suggestions/3456724-size-height-of-bar-graph-based-on-contents-when-co) - you can set height of the graph according to the number of bars/categories you want to use: https://jsfiddle.net/vnx2ghgv/3/